# Unable to change the app name in cocoa project?

Tags: macos, cocoa, info.plist

I am trying to change the display name of a MacOS application. This app may have different names on different localizations.

So I have added an `InfoPlist.strings` file with these keys:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "My Amazing App";
"CFBundleName" = "My Amazing App";
```

when I build the project the app is generated with this name `My App`, not `My Amazing App`. `My App` is the name the project has on Xcode.

My `Info.plist` file has these keys:

```
Bundle Name = ${PRODUCT_NAME}
Bundle display name = My Amazing App
ExecutabLe file = ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
Bundle identifier = $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)
```

Any ideas why I am unable to rename that? I want the app to be called `My Amazing App.app`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need to touch Info.plist.

1. In the file navigator on the left side, select project file.
2. In the Utility panel on the right side, select file inspector.
3. Change project name.
4. Press enter and done!

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This will do the job if your app is not localized but anyway there is something wrong with the InfoPlist.strings because this later is the way to do it in a localized way. Anyway, thanks. I will accept this answer unless someone shows how to fix the initial problem.

Comment: Info.strings Localisation should work? Have you changed the system locale and try again?